# How do I pass information to this API endpoint?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm working with an API that has no documentation I know what the endpoint is but I don't know how to pass and where the right parameters.
I'm working with Axios in a React project.

This is the endpoint I need: 
https://apiname.com/v1.0/metadata/noun/search?nouns=game,genre,country&include_aliases=true

The thing is if I pass the "Name, genre, country" manually it shows me an error.
I can get fetch other data from the API so I know it's working but I have no idea how to access or work with this endpoint.

This is how I try to pass it manually

```
axios.get("https://apiname.com/v1.0/metadata/noun/search?nouns=Minecraft,Adventure,Canada&include_aliases=true", header)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)

            })
```

Error: "Request failed with status code 405"

Comment: given endpoint is incorrect

Comment: 405 method is invalid, maybe you should try `axios.post`